# How to naturalize "artificial" keys in initial_data.json?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to load data from my `initial_data.json` file, I get the error `IntegrityError: Could not load auth.Permission(pk=24): columns content_type_id, codename are not unique`.

As I learned from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942214/django-loading-users-using-inital-data-json), it is necessary to add the `-n` argument, when exporting data to `initial_data.json` (`manage.py dumpdata -n auth.Permission`).

But how can I correct this error now, when I **already** exported it without natural keys, deleted the old database and can't reimport the data due to the error stated before?

I tried to change the `pk` field to another number (see below), but it didn't help (new error: `IntegrityError: Could not load auth.Permission(pk=10024): columns content_type_id, codename are not unique`).

[image: Changing the pk field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing from the JSON file all entries except data from my model and importing them.